# Is it possible to remove folder prefix from a `ls` command

Tags: bash, shell, directory, ls

I am in a bash script and I want to get the list of all files (let say all jar files). I execute the command `ls -1 lib/*.jar` and I get the output:

```
lib/mylib_1.jar
lib/mylib_2.jar
...
```

Is there any option to have the following output:

```
mylib_1.jar
mylib_2.jar
...
```

Making `cd lib` before is not an option as I am in a loop and need to be in the parent folder for the actions I want to do inside the loop.

I tried to find information by typing `man ls` but I did not find any solution.

A solution with another command would be good as long I can pipe it to my `ls` command or self sufficient.

Comment: What are you doing with the names of those files? Are you just listing them to the terminal, or are you passing them to another program or script (individually or as a list)? The correct way to handle this depends on how the filenames are used.

Comment: The idea was to do some statistics about third party libs on a multi-module java project. I just wanted the list and make a sort and uniq after

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) you should use `find` instead. Then you can also execute `basename` on each file to strip the leading directories:

```
find lib/ -name '*.jar' -exec basename {} \;
```

Comment: Ok this way is perfect for me as well.

Comment: Also see the `-maxdepth` option.

Answer (score 16):

With GNU `find` there is no need to run `basename` for every single file, this will be much faster (especially if there is a lot of files):

```
find lib -name '*.jar' -printf '%P\n'
```

Answer (score 11):

How about `(cd lib && echo *.jar)`, assuming that you don't have whitespace or special characters in the file names.  Parent script never changes directory.

Comment: Spaces won't be an issue either.

Comment: This is a good idea and will probably be the fastest option. I would do `printf '%s\n' *.jar` to get each file on a different line though.

Comment: Or even `printf '%s\0' *.jar` to eliminate whitespace issues (although this is not the Q).

Answer (score 6):

As Josh Jolly said in his answer, you should never parse `ls`, use the approach in his answer instead. Still, here's an `awk` solution to remove paths from file names, just don't use it with ls:

```
find . | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
```

The `-F'/'` sets the field separator to `/` which means that the last field, `$NF`, will be the file name.

Answer (score 1):

`find` is probably the way to go, but if you *really, really do* (you don't) want to strip off `lib/` from `ls -1`, you can use `sed`:

```
$ ls -1 lib/*.jar | sed 's#^lib/##'
mylib_1.jar
mylib_2.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) with a --max-args (or the shorter alias -n) parameter:

`ls --quoting-style=c -1 lib/*.jar | xargs --max-args 1 basename
ls --quoting-style=c -1 lib/*.jar | xargs -n 1 basename`

Note that we use `--quoting-style=c` to make sure spaces in filenames do not screw up xargs.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thank you! Found this gem on another stack exchange. You can introduce quotes to ls results with --quoting-style=c. So the resulting full command would be: ` ls --quoting-style=c -1 lib/*.jar | xargs --max-args 1 basename`

Answer (score -1):

An alternative way solve your query is to list all the files using `ls -R`. Combine the output of ls command with grep to list only .jar files.
You can use following command to do the same for your query:

```
ls -R lib | grep jar| grep -v jar*
```

Comment: This would fail badly if there were a subdirectory that also contains jar files, or a file named for example "list-of-jars.txt".

Comment: grep -v jar* would filter out results with file named like your quoted example.

Comment: true. it would also filter out all the intended files.  Now I look at it again, I can see no circumstances where the command you suggest would actually produce any output at all...

Comment: No, it would display files like `mylib_2.jar` and filter out files like `list-of-jars.txt`.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I just tried it.  `find development -name '*.jar' | wc -l` -> `70`.  `ls -R development | grep jar| grep -v jar*` -> no output at all.